# svn diff offline

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, commit, offline

dueto historical reason, I do have a very old vm with eclipse 3.2 running and a lot of uncommited code. The source code management was svn, but this server doesn't exist any more. Now everything is located in a git repository.

My question is, is there any way to run the svn diff or something comparable to create a patch file I can commit to a git branch? There should be, because eclipse knows what has been changed (black star at each changed file). Or is there any other simple and easy way I just don't see?

Thanks, Christian

Comment: The project is already in git, but the uncommited changes not. So I only want to commit these changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion diffs can be applied using [patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29).

First, create the diff. Use Eclipse to create the patch for you using [*Team > Create Patch*](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-68c.htm). Alternatively, in your svn working copy:

```
svn diff > my-changes.diff
```

Then clone the new git repository. Use EGit, or run:

```
git clone ..../project.git
cd project
```

Now apply the patch. Use Eclipse to apply the patch file with [*Team > Apply Patch*](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-68c.htm). Alternatively, run:

```
patch -p0 < /path/to/my-changes.diff
```

You might need to change the `0` to a different value, depending on where you run svn diff from. See the [patch manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) for an explanation of the `-p` option.

Comment: workes perfekt, don't know why eclipse yesterday complained about missing svn server, during the patch creation. Now it works. Thanks for the Step by Step guide.